# Data segment of ELF binary not loaded by GRUB with Multiboot

Tags: c, x86-64, nasm, osdev, multiboot

I'm creating my own OS just for fun.

My kernel is a 64-bits ELF binary with the multiboot header. I use grub-mkrescue to build an .iso file to boot on my kernel and I test it with qemu + tianocore (UEFI).

My kernel is composed of a simple main function which print pixels on the screen. But my global variables, saved in the `.data` segment, does not seem to be loaded. Indeed, if I use a global variable `pixels` to set the number of pixels to draw no pixel is printed (but if `pixels` variable is local to the main function then the pixels are drawn).

The `loader.s` (multiboot header + call kernel start function) :

```
section .multiboot               
align 4
    dd 0x1BADB002               ; magic
    dd 0x6                      ; flags
    dd - (0x1BADB002 + 0x6)     ; checksum
    dd 0                        ; header_addr
    dd 0                        ; load_addr
    dd 0                        ; load_end_addr
    dd 0                        ; bss_end_addr
    dd 0                        ; entry_addr
    dd 0                        ; mode_type
    dd 1024                     ; width
    dd 768                      ; height
    dd 32                       ; depth

section .text
global _start
extern kstart                    ; defined in the C file

_start:
        cli                      ; block interrupts
        mov rsp, stack_space     ; set stack pointer
    
        call kstart              ; call kernel start function
        hlt                      ; halt the CPU

section .bss
resb 8192                        ; 8KB for stack
stack_space:
```

The kernel C code `kmain.c` with start function :

```
unsigned int pixels = 10;

void put_pixel(unsigned int i)
{
    unsigned int *graphics_memory = (unsigned int *) 0xA0000;
    graphics_memory[i] = 0xffffffff;
}

int kstart(unsigned int addr)
{
    unsigned int p;

    for (p = 0; p < pixels; p++)
        put_pixel(p);

    return 0;
}
```

The linker script `link.ld` :

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 1M;     
    
    .text ALIGN (0x1000) :      /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)                /* all text sections from all files */
    }

    .rodata ALIGN (0x1000) :    /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(.rodata*)             /* all read-only data sections from all files */
    }
    
    .data ALIGN (0x1000) :      /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(.data)                /* all data sections from all files */
    }

    .bss ALIGN (0x1000) :       /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(COMMON)               /* all COMMON sections from all files */
        *(.bss)                 /* all bss sections from all files */
    }
}
```

From what I understand, the bootloader GRUB will read the ELF header and load the segments. I'm right ? Did I miss something ?

Comment: Grub Multiboot doesn't put the processor in long mode (64-bit mode). Multiboot only guarantees your 32-bit protected mode with the A20 line enabled and that is it. 64-bit code will not behave properly in 32-bit protected mode. Your code likely won't work until you add code to put the processor in long mode before calling the kernel.

Comment: Thank for your leads. I tried this [tuto](http://ringzeroandlower.com/2017/08/08/x86-64-kernel-boot.html) (Grub with x86 64-bit long mode) and my data segment is correctly loaded ! I did not know about this long mode stuff, I will explore that to adapt my current code.